# grouping and then sorting

Tags: spring, mongodb, sorting, grouping

I prepare aggregation to group, but unfortunely I can't sort output based on date. Here is the aggregation

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
            match(Criteria.where(CREATED_CRITERIA).gte(midnight).lte(now)),
            unwind(list),
            group(list + ".label").sum(list + ".value").as("value"),
             sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "_id") 
            );
```

Object looks like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56d9549e6a082cbc68dcedeb"),
    "created" : ISODate("2016-03-04T09:01:00.000Z"),
    "trucker" : NumberLong(0),
    "toProcess" : NumberLong(0),
    "smsSent" : NumberLong(0),
    "correct" : NumberLong(0),
    "redirected" : NumberLong(0),
    "truckerPerHours" : [ 
        {
            "label" : "Fri Mar 04 10:00:00 CET 2016",
            "value" : 0
        }
    ],
    "toProcessPerHours" : [ 
        {
            "label" : "Fri Mar 04 10:00:00 CET 2016",
            "value" : 0
        }
    ],
    "smsSentPerHours" : [ 
        {
            "label" : "Fri Mar 04 10:00:00 CET 2016",
            "value" : 0
        }
    ],
    "correctPerHours" : [ 
        {
            "label" : "Fri Mar 04 10:00:00 CET 2016",
            "value" : 0
        }
    ],
    "redirectedPerHours" : [ 
        {
            "label" : "Fri Mar 04 10:00:00 CET 2016",
            "value" : 0
        }
    ],
    "truckerPerBranch" : [],
    "toProcessPerBranch" : [],
    "smsSentPerBranch" : [],
    "correctPerBranch" : [],
    "redirectedPerBranch" : []
}
```

I would like to group and then sort based on "created" Date, at the moment I sort based on label which is not good idea since it is a string.

Answer (score 3):

You can include the date field inside the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline stage using the **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** operator, after which you can then sort the resulting pipeline on that field. Two examples that show this approach follow:

---

**Mongo Shell:**

```
pipeline = [
    { 
        "$match": {
            "created": { "$lte": now, "$gte": midnight }
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$smsSentPerHours" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$smsSentPerHours.label",
            "value": { "$sum": "$smsSentPerHours.value" },
            "created": { "$first": "$created" }
        }
    },
    { "$sort": { "created": 1 } }
]

db.collection.aggregate(pipeline);
```

---

**Spring Data MongoDB:**

```
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.*;

MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = repository.getMongoTemplate();
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
    match(Criteria.where(CREATED_CRITERIA).gte(midnight).lte(now)),
    unwind(list),
    group(list + ".label")
        .sum(list + ".value").as("value")
        .first("created").as("created"),
    project("created").and("value").previousOperation(),
    sort(ASC, "created")
);

AggregationResults<OutputType> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg,
                                            "collection", OutputType.class);
List<OutputType> mappedResult = result.getMappedResults();
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use *Projections*... Try this:

If you want to return a list of entities with agregation function you may use Projections. In criteria this is done through ProjectionList and Projections. e.g.

```
    final ProjectionList props = Projections.projectionList();
    //your group by conditions here:
    props.add(Projections.groupProperty("group property 1"));
    props.add(Projections.groupProperty("group property 2"));
    //your criteria with group by conditions here:
    crit.setProjection(props);
    crit.add(Order.desc("created"));
```